# MP3 Player, play button has no sound

Tags: java, swing, audio-player

I'm trying to get an mp3 play button to work using JLayer. I get no errors but it doesn't play any sound. I added all the required jar files to the library and followed many tutorials so the code should work but I just don't get any sound. (P/S: I don't have an mp3 plugin)

```
try
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Trying");
    FIS = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Jun\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Player\\src\\Songs\\NumaNuma.mp3");
    BIS = new BufferedInputStream(FIS);

    playSong = new javazoom.jl.player.Player(BIS);
    playSong.play();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Occured " + e);
}

new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try 
        {
            playSong.play();
        } 
        catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Occured " + ex);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Besides JLayer, you don't need any additional plugins. Did you debug your code?

Comment: I think it should have a method to check if it is already playing.. you should write somethign like `while(!playersong.isplaying()){playsong.play()}` because play will be called only once and as the thread ends it will stop.

Comment: Yes I debugged the code it did go into the try part and did the play method  and then it went to the closing bracket and finished. So it acted like it did play the song but really it didn't. I wondered if it was a fault with my netbeans but it couldn't be as I tried the same code on many computers now.

Answer (score 0):

The player works now. I was trying to play an mp4 that I renamed as an mp3 not fully realising that that wouldn't work until I used an actual mp3 song.